# How to restrict Person field to an Active Directory group?

Tags: sharepoint-online, person, azure-active-directory

In SharePoint Online, I have a **Person** column attached to my list, which is restricted to showing people in a SharePoint group named "All non-admin O365 users".  This SharePoint group contains a single Azure Active Directory group named "All-NonAdmin-O365-Users", which itself contains the relevant people.

When I try to use this column to search for people, it cannot find any people that are listed inside the AD Group (with error "No Result Found").  The people I am trying to enter are definitely members of the "All-NonAdmin-O365-Users" AD Group.  For comparison, if I allow all users in this field (no restriction), then it can find everyone just fine.

Am I missing something, or does this mean SharePoint Online cannot see the contents of the AD Group?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed SharePoint is specifically tagging AD groups if it is called in SharePoint group somewhat like "MyGroup Owners", "MyGroup Members", but as we know the group that we meant was "MyGroup" but in SharePoint it specifies whether if you meant to call the group's Owners or its Members.

Can you try if in the Audience box in your list column settings you can see the "All-NonAdmin-O365-Users Members" ?

I believe this group 'All-NonAdmin-O365-Users' is an o365 group setuped in the Admin center. Let me know if im mistaken.

Hope the concept helps! Happy Learning!

Comment: No, there is no "All-NonAdmin-O365-Users Members" variant of my group - Only "All-NonAdmin-O365-Users".  The group itself is a Security group that is synchronized from an on-premises Active Directory...

Comment: Ahh I see, so its a security group, in this case it won't show up unless its a a plain o365 group (im not sure for distribution type of group). 

Also the "Members" in "All-NonAdmin-O365-Users Members" sharepoint is appending it from "All-NonAdmin-O365-Users" o365 group meaning, it is referring to the members of the "All-NonAdmin-O365-Users" o355 group so if you type in for example youre giving a permission if you try to seach that group it will show you, "All-NonAdmin-O365-Users Members" instead of "All-NonAdmin-O365-Users" cause it is referring to the group's Members.